# IIS stops listening

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, netsh

I have a Windows server that periodically stops responding to requests on a particular IP address. I can find no reason/cause, but I'll confess right off the bat that I'm not a sys/network admin.

The only solution that I've found to bring the sites on the server back up is to instruct the server to stop listening to that IP (I must delete first because, although it's not listening for that IP, it seems to think that it is):

`netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=***.***.***.14`

And then instruct it to listen again:

`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=***.***.***.14`

I usually have to do this once a week.

What could be causing this behavior? I'm not seeing anything in the logs that indicate an issue at the point where my sites go down.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I've discovered that our sys admin has the server rebooting every Sunday night at 3am. The above issue appears only after reboot. IIS believes that it's listening on the IP above, but still requires the `netsh http delete/listen` every Monday morning.

Why wouldn't that survive a reboot?

Comment: static IP or DHCP reservation?  Any chance another device is grabbing a duplicate IP?

Comment: It has two static IP's assigned to it. Only one seems to have this issue. It's a good thought. I'll try to get access to the DHCP server's logs.

Comment: I'm not seeing any IP conflicts...

Comment: sorry, I'm not an expert in IIS.  Other thoughts are local A/V or if it always works fine on the other IPs then perhaps remove that problematic IP and replace it with another and test.  If all goes fine for a while, then something isn't right with that IP on the network.

Comment: Is your Site Binding in IIS set to * or that specific IP address? Is it possible you have another service competing for that ip:port binding? (another HTTP server, or app/service that has a web UI) The next time you encounter it, try a `netstat -ano` to see what PID is associated with `***.***.***.14` and that port. Verify that it is IIS and not something else listening.

Comment: Do you have a HOSTS file configured on the server that's setting any IPs after reboot? Have you tried to update the nic drivers? And it wasn't clear, is the other IP functioning properly after reboot? Are they both on the same subnet?

Comment: @htm11h, the .23 IP still functions after reboot. The hosts files does associate the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) with a particular URL. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: As long as there is nothing else in the HOSTS file, then yes that appears ok. I would check for driver updates to the network cards as well.

Comment: When did it first start happening? After reboot cycle was introduced or had that always been in place? If you can pin down the date it was first observed, you can review your system and application logs for any changes made before it manifested - patches, hotfixes, driver updates. No other services or applications have exhibited issues on the same system? Can you replicate the issue by performing an IISreset - if it is associated to an app then maybe it's not cleanly shutting down. Failing that you could look into DebugDiag to help troubleshoot further.